# Aliasing Chrome in terminal with a http:// prefix

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, scripting, alias

I am trying to add an alias to terminal that will allow me to say 'chrome github.com' and open the url I have provided in chrome.

I'd like to add http:// to the alias so I can just type the URL without http:// at the front.

Here's what I've got now:

> alias chrome="open -a \"Google Chrome\" http://"

Currently with this, if I just call Chrome, a new tab will open up and calling it with a url(minus the http://) will return:

> The file /Users/name/github.com does not exist.

Comment: Does `open -a "Google Chrome" http://github.com` work from the terminal? Because you use `open`, are you on MacOS? Please add the operating system to the tags.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes I am on MacOS, I've added it to the tags as well. Running open -a "Google Chrome" http://github.com does work from the terminal, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a function, which works like alias, is more flexible and readable.

```
chrome() {
       open -a "Google Chrome" http://"$@"
}
```

`alias` adds a space after it's invokation. So with your alias `chrome github.com` does `open -a "Google Chrome" http:// github.com`.